# DNS Delegar un subdominio con Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, redes

Tengo dos servidores de ubuntu, srv1 y srv3. srv1 es el servidor principal y srv3 es un subdominio al que quiero delegar. El problema es que no transfiere los datos del srv3 al srv1.

Ejemplo de estructura:
[image: Estructura]

**SERVIDOR 1**

/etc/bind/named.conf.local

[image: named.conf.local]

/etc/bind/db.jt.test

[image: db.jt.test]

[image: db.jt.test]

/etc/bind/db.172.30

[image: db.172.30]

**SERVIDOR 2**

/etc/bind/named.conf.local

[image: named.conf.local]

/etc/bind/db.srv3.jt.local

[image: db.srv3.jt.local]

/etc/bind/db.172.30

[image: db.172.30]

**ERRORES OBTENIDOS y COMPROBACIONES**

En el SERVIDOR 1: 
El error está en que no pasa la información del srv3 al srv1, no se donde puede estar el fallo en la configuración.

[image: error principal]

En el SERVIDOR 2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUCIÓN:**

Añadir al final del fichero /etc/bind/db.jt.test (SERVIDOR 1):

```
*.srv3.jt.test. IN A 172.30.0.17
```

Y si con lo anterior no funciona modificar "delega IN NS srv3.jt.test." por:

```
srv3 IN NS srv3.jt.test.
```

Con eso hace referencia a que todo lo que se encuentre en ese subdominio hay que buscarlo en esa dirección IP del servidor 3.

[image: SOLUCION]

Información encontrada en: [DNS para delegar autoridad a subdominio](https://www.enmimaquinafunciona.com/pregunta/4701/como-debo-configurar-dns-para-delegar-autoridad-para-subdominios)